# Access two indexes in a list and create a list of new objects using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list of DateTime Objects like this and they are in order of 15 minute intervals

11:15 AM
11:30 AM
11:45 AM and so on...

```
IList<DateTimeOffset> list;
```

My class looks something like this

```
/// <summary>Start Time</summary>
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startTime")]
public DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }

/// <summary>End Time</summary>
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endTime")]
public DateTimeOffset EndTime { get; set; }
```

I want to go through the list and create a resulting object like:

StartTime - 11:15 AM
End - 11:30 AM

StartTime - 11:30 AM
End - 11:45 AM

Is there a Linq way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your result is the combination of {nth, nth + 1} list items, then you could do:

```
        var result = list.Join(list, 
                         x => list.IndexOf(x) + 1, 
                         x => list.IndexOf(x), 
                         (x, y) => new YourClass
                            {
                                StartTime = x,
                                EndTime = y
                            });
```

But I think it would be cleaner to simply use a for loop for and take list[i],list[i+1]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your class:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

and this is your initial List:

```
DateTime first = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 11, 15, 0);
List<DateTimeOffset> list = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
list.Add(new DateTimeOffset(first));
list.Add(new DateTimeOffset(first.AddMinutes(15)));
list.Add(new DateTimeOffset(first.AddMinutes(30)));
```

the LINQ code is:

```
List<YourClass> newList = (from i in list.Take(list.Count - 1)
                           select new YourClass
                           {
                               StartDate = i,
                               EndDate = list[list.IndexOf(i) + 1]
                           }).ToList();
```